# FtpWebRequest 30 minute time out

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, filezilla, ftpwebrequest

My code is experiencing a time out exception after exactly 30 minutes when downloading a large file over FTP. The server is [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) running on Windows. We have an SSL certificate configured with options `Enable FTP over SSL/TLS support (FTPS)` and `Allow explicit FTP over TLS` enabled. I have access to the server and the [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) configuration but can't see anything that might cause this behavior. Below is the source code which is running on .NET 4.6.2 on a Windows 2012 Server Machine. It can download files from the FTP server but will time out with the exception (listed below) after exactly 30 minutes if the file takes longer than 30 minutes to download.

As a test I have used [FileZilla Client](https://filezilla-project.org/), running from the same client PC, to download multiple large files from the same server end point simultaneously so that the download for each file took over 30 minutes to complete. No errors occurred in this scenario.

I have searched on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) as well as [Google](http://google.com) but nothing promising turned up. If anyone has some tips on where to look (server side or client side) I would be most appreciative.

---

#### Application code

```
public class FtpFileDownloader
{
    // log4net
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(FtpFileDownloader));

    public void DownloadFile()
    {
        // setting the SecurityProtocol did not change the outcome, both were tried. Originally it was not set at all.
        // ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;


        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        const int timeout = 7200000;
        const string file = "some-existing-file";
        try
        {
            var request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("uri-path-to-file");
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.Timeout = -1;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = timeout;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password");
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.EnableSsl = true;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            Logger.Debug($"Downloading '{file}'");
            using (var response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
            using (var sourceStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var targetStream = new FileStream("some-target-on-disk", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                try
                {
                    sourceStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
                    targetStream.Flush();
                    Logger.Debug($"Finished download '{file}'");
                }
                catch (Exception exInner)
                {
                    Logger.Error($"Error occurred trying to download file '{file}'.", exInner);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error($"Error occurred trying to dispose streams when downloading file '{file}'.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Application Log

```
ERROR FtpFileDownloader - Error occurred trying to download file 'some-existing-file'.
System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FtpDataStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.Stream.InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination)
   at FtpFileDownloader.DownloadFile

ERROR FtpFileDownloader - Error occurred trying to dispose streams when downloading file 'some-existing-file'.
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.Abort(Exception e)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.CheckContinuePipeline()
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.DataStreamClosed(CloseExState closeState)
   at System.Net.FtpDataStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
   at System.Net.FtpDataStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
   at FtpFileDownloader.DownloadFile
```

---

#### FileZilla - General Settings

```
 Listen on these ports: 21
  Max. number of users: 0 (infinite)
     Number of threads: 2
    Connection timeout: 120 (seconds)
   No Transfer timeout: 9000 (seconds)
           Log timeout: 60 (seconds)
```

---

#### FileZilla Server Log

```
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - (not logged in) (194.123.75.2)> Connected on port 21, sending welcome message...
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - (not logged in) (194.123.75.2)> 220 Welcome
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - (not logged in) (194.123.75.2)> AUTH TLS
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - (not logged in) (194.123.75.2)> 234 Using authentication type TLS
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - (not logged in) (194.123.75.2)> TLS connection established
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - (not logged in) (194.123.75.2)> USER  my-user-account
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - (not logged in) (194.123.75.2)> 331 Password required for my-user-account
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - (not logged in) (194.123.75.2)> PASS **************
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> 230 Logged on
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> PBSZ 0
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> 200 PBSZ=0
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> PROT P
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> 200 Protection level set to P
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> OPTS utf8 on
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> 202 UTF8 mode is always enabled. No need to send this command.
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> PWD
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> 257 "/" is current directory.
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> TYPE I
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> 200 Type set to I
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> PASV
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (IP-ADDRESS,245,222)
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> RETR path-to-file
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> 150 Opening data channel for file download from server of "/path-to-file"
23-2-2018 11:40:40 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> TLS connection for data connection established
23-2-2018 12:10:41 - my-user-account (194.123.75.2)> disconnected.
```

*Notice that there is 30 minutes between the disconnect (last line) and the line before it. If it had completed the transfer with success there would also be a line that read `226 Successfully transferred "/path-to-file"` before the `disconnected` line*

---

Progress update:

- (2018.02.20) I asked our network team to check the fire wall rules but they could not find anything of interest.
- (2018.02.22) I found that the version of FileZilla Server being used is `0.9.43 beta` (*release date 2014-01-02 according to the change log*). Although I did not find anything in the change log that suggests this behavior was ever a fixed bug I am going to upgrade to the latest version `0.9.60.2` (*release date 2017-02-08*) and execute the test again. Will report back within 24 hours.
- (2018.02.23) FileZilla has been updated to the latest version. This did not fix the problem, I updated the server log but it looks almost identical to the previous log with the exception being that this last transfer took place over TLS instead of SSL.
- (2018.02.23) I found the following link [Timeouts on large files](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Timeouts_on_large_files) on the FileZilla support page. I am going to push it back to the network staff of our hosting provider to take another look.
- (2018.02.27) It turned out that the company firewall (*network where the client executes*) and not the hosting firewall (*network where FileZilla is hosted*) was the culprit. It was configured to drop idle connections after `1800` seconds. A rule has been added to override this between these 2 end points.

---

#### Culprit / Answer

It turned out that the company firewall (*network where the client executes*) and not the hosting firewall (*network where FileZilla is hosted*) was the culprit. It was configured to drop idle connections after `1800` seconds. A rule has been added to override this between these 2 end points.

Comment: Have you check firewall and network settings? Fillezilla should not break in the middle of the transfer that is wierd...

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis - Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately that did not change the outcome.

Comment: Are you sure the file is not corrupted in any way? Can you use an ftp software to download it, and if so, can you open the downloaded copy?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - No, the file is not corrupted. The file is recreated on the server every day but if I switch the code to run single threaded it can successfully complete a download within 30 minutes. The original/problem code is multi-threaded and as it saturates the available bandwidth the download takes longer than 30 minutes to complete and fails at exactly 30.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Just to clarify: by multi-threaded I mean I am downloading multiple files simultaneously. There is a list of files and the above code is called from a parallel foreach.

Comment: What it you try to download a single, but really, really large file, one that will take more than 30 minutes to download?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Good suggestion, I just did that (hence it took a while for me to respond). Unfortunately the result is the same.

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis - thanks, I have done so.

Comment: What's the No Transfer timeout set to on the server in General Settings?

Comment: The server timeout settings are for the control/browser connections only, transfers use their own connections and should never be closed mid stream. It must be a router or firewall killing the connection after 30 mins.

Comment: @BL - 9000 seconds.

Comment: It sounds like an idle timeout (FileZilla server). It doesn't matter it works with FileZilla client, it's not working the way your code does. What happens if you set keepalive to true, use a long timeout (e.g. 6 hours), make your transfer async and "reuse" your request every 20 minutes to download a small dummy file?

Comment: Also: do you have load balancers or other perimetral devices?

Comment: @FrancescoB. - Setting `KeepAlive` to `true` and the `TimeOut` to `-1` which in infinite did not change the outcome. Not sure what else I should change in the code with that. I have not tried anything with reusing the request every xx minutes. Also this server is not behind a loadbalancer but is out of network.  I have asked the network admins to check the firewall but they could not come up with anything. The test with FileZilla Client was done to see if that failed as well, then the cause would not be related to my code but with that working I had a feeling maybe it was code specific.

Comment: Question: could you post your FileZilla Server configuration, like in [this image](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/download/file.php?id=2893)?

Comment: wow, your connectionTimeout is just 2 minutes? Could you raise it to 3600 seconds?

Comment: Regarding your latest update, I've found that document as well and I was preparing an answer based on that. What bothers me though is that with another FTP client, you succeed. I suggest you use a networking tool (wireshark etc) to see what FileZilla does different than your .NET application.

Comment: FileZilla may be encountering the same problem but it is using an FTP REST (resume Transfer) command with a file offset.  The generic .net ftp client dos not offer a resume at file byte offset command.  The other detail that a separate ftp utility or library may provide you is that it guarantees the last byte is written before you see the final file in the target location.  So you app or script knows when it sees the file it is done.  The resume transfer try again feature and the rename file when done are often options on individual ftp utilities.

Comment: You're supposed to send NOOP FTP commands regularly. You can't do that with FtpWebRequest, see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5d2b67e8-d9cb-4025-be1b-aa4379e8fa5a/ftpwebrequest-and-timeouts?forum=netfxnetcom and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321097/how-to-send-arbitrary-ftp-commands-in-c-sharp

Comment: Probably an unhelpful comment, but I've had an issue where one FTP program wouldn't even list the contents of a directory but yet Filezilla client would without a problem.  My FZ server runs in Azure virtual machine and configured for SSL.  What helped me was to turn off the "Disable IP Check" under "Security Settings".  One of the comments above me seems to be true though, where a NOOP should be sent regularly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you should try another implementation of FTP protocol client that isn't built on top of the `FtpWebRequest`.

Related issues exist for a long time, they don't have a clear solution or answer. So I would try something like [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP), it uses Winsock API directly. XML Documentation Comment states that `DownloadFile()` should handle large file downloads well:

```
/// <summary>
/// Downloads the specified file onto the local file system.
/// High-level API that takes care of various edge cases internally.
/// Supports very large files since it downloads data in chunks.
/// </summary>
```

For more information check:

- [Downloading large files(~150MB) from FTP server hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950211/downloading-large-files150mb-from-ftp-server-hangs) discussion on StackOverflow
- [FtpWebRequest is Broken](http://mattmitchell.com.au/ftpwebrequest-is-broken/) article by Matt Mitchell
- [Winsock API](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958787.aspx) page on Microsoft TechNet
- Source Code section in [Partial FTP Downloader](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27439/Partial-FTP-Downloader) article by Elmue

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation on [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP), that looks like a much easier to use library compared to the built in `FtpWebRequest` with more functionality as well. The end cause was a firewall issue but you could also argue that with a proper library it would have never been an issue to begin with. Either way, I believe this answer best addresses the question. Thank you.

Comment: May I ask what was the firewall issue? It can be interesting to know anyway... thank you :)

Comment: @FrancescoB. - see also the question which was updated with the cause listed at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I don't think there's a "mistake" in your code; it's just that the control connection dies out after 30 minutes even though the transfer connection doesn't timeout. Perhaps it won't even be necessary to alter you KeepAlive and Timeout values, just try to reuse your request every 20 minutes or so with a dummy download: that way you will reset the control connection timer.

Btw, somewhere I've read that 30 minutes is a standard timeout for FileZilla Server, which is based on 6 keep-alive configured to be sent every 300 seconds (which gives your 30 minutes experience). 
If you could try with another FTP/FTPS server you'd probably find out a different idle timeout and would not bang against that 30 minute limit (but a different one).

So, personally I would invest in making the code below `async`, so the execution flow goes on after the enclosing `using` and you can enter a loop where every 20 minutes you reuse your request (and its control connection) to make a dummy download.
Of course FileZilla Client doesn't need a dummy download because it operates at a lower level and probably sends TCP commands to keep the control connection alive.

```
using (var response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
        using (var sourceStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var targetStream = new FileStream("some-target-on-disk", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            try
            {
                sourceStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
                targetStream.Flush();
                Logger.Debug($"Finished download '{file}'");
            }
            catch (Exception exInner)
            {
                Logger.Error($"Error occurred trying to download file '{file}'.", exInner);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you don't wanna make that code async, you can pass the `request` to another thread and have it keep the connection alive (i.e. downloading a small file, e.g. a 1 byte size one).

Comment: _somewhere I've read that 30 minutes is a standard timeout for FileZilla Server_ It might be better to find that `somewhere`, because I've searched for that, and I didn't find anything. Also what if at some point that 30 changes to 15? I don't like the `every 20 minutes` bit. A better solution would be to find the offending piece of software and not trying to circumvent it.

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis About the source you're right, unfortunately I couldn't find it before posting (or now); one [link](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=6406) states the same thing in a rather indirect way. Also you're right, the 20 minutes example was... an example, based on the current server behavior. Clearly and in general, if any server changes its behavior (e.g. in terms of policies, timeout or certificates included), clients should be notified.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar [issue reported in FluentFTP here](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/issues/387) and [stefanolazzarato posted a work-around](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/issues/387#issuecomment-522883713):

> ```cs
> int progress = -1;
> try
> {
>    FtpClient client = new FtpClient("HOST");
>    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USER", "PASSWORD");
>    client.Connect();
>
>    client.UploadFile("LOCALPATH/FILENAME", "REMOTEPATH/FILENAME",
>        FtpExists.Overwrite,
>        false,
>        FtpVerify.None,
>        new Progress<FtpProgress>(p => progress = Convert.ToInt32(p.Progress))
>        );
> }
> catch (Exception ex)
> {
>    if (progress == 100 && ex is FluentFTP.FtpException && ex.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException is TimeoutException)
>    {
>        // Upload complete
>        // LOG Info exception
>    }
>    else
>    {
>        // LOG Fatal exception
>        throw;
>    }
> }
> ```